# Join command not giving output when comparing large files

Tags: shell-script, join

[image]I have 2 files as below with one file of 20 gb and another in MBs

```
file1.txt (100 MB)

6000000
6000001
6000003
```

```
file2.txt (20 gb) 

6000000;dgdfgdfgdfgdfgdggeewtwtwtwetewtt
6000003;eryeyyrtuytityiytititityityiytii
6000005;qwrwqrwqrrrrerewrwerewrwrrrewrew
```

I want all matching contents and output like :

```
6000000;dgdfgdfgdfgdfgdggeewtwtwtwetewtt
6000003;eryeyyrtuytityiytititityityiytii
```

Now, I used sort command for both files and used below join command but I do not get any output ? Please help what's wrong here?

```
join -t';' file1.txt file2.txt >> file3.txt
```

Comment: Wouldn't both files need the *same* separator?

Comment: I works with the above examples, but fails if I convert the files to DOS format. Could you show the output of `file file1.txt file2.txt` and `head file1.txt file2.txt | cat -A`? Are these files form a Windows program?

Comment: and "ls -l file3.txt" if you please.

Comment: @FelixJN please find screenshoot, I am trying on CentOS linux.

Comment: @jay Please do **not** post screenshots, but rather copy the text here! You also missed the `| cat -A` part in the second command. Nevertheless, the result "ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators" tells you that you indeed do have DOS-type line feeds.

Comment: @FelixJN so could you guide how to proceed ?

Comment: If you're happy with one or several of the answers, upvote them.  If one is solving your issue, [accepting it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) would be the best way of saying "Thank You!"  Accepting an answer also indicates to _future_ readers that the answer actually solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your file `file1.txt` (at least, possibly both) is a DOS text file.  When used as text files on a Unix system, DOS text files have an extra carriage-return character at the end of each line.

This extra carriage return at the end of each line interferes with the interpretation of the data in the first file in such a way that `join` will try to match data with carriage-returns at the end (from the first file) with data that does not have carriage-returns at the end (the first field from the second file). This means no pairs of join keys will ever match and you get no output.

Convert your files to Unix text files using a tool such as `dos2unix` and try your `join` command again.

Also consider using a non-privilegied user account rather than the root user account when not performing system administration tasks. Using the root account for day-to-day tasks is irresponsible as it disables most security measures that Unix systems usually enforce (such as basic file and directory permissions etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You have DOS-type line feeds (`CRLF`) and `join` won't understand the files.

- **Option 1**: Convert the files using `dos2unix` from the repositories.

```
dos2unix file1.txt file2.txt
```

note that this will alter the files - depending on what program reads them next, you may need to reconvert the result via - guess it - `unix2dos file3.txt`.

- **Option 2**: Use `awk` with `\r\n` as record separators:

```
awk ' BEGIN {FS=";" ; RS="\r\n" }
      NR==FNR { marker[$1]=$1 }
      NR!=FNR && $1 in marker ' file1.txt file2.txt
```

The advantage here being that the line feed character stays intact and that the 20GB file is only read, not processed - which should be better regarding writing of temporary files.

**note** I assumed that BOTH files are DOS-style in case of the `awk` solution. `file` does not really tell this if "very long lines" are involved.

Comment: @jay Why would you be running the `join` in the background?  In any case, it does return, immediately, just press `Enter` to re-display the prompt.

Comment: just in case if it gets timeout, but fortunately it comes out and now it looks good, sincere thanks to all here and @FelixJN

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others already, yout first file has to be converted to unix line endings beforehand. However, you don't need to alter the file itself. Instead you could try to convert it on the fly.

Change your command line to following:

```
join -t';' <(dos2unix file1.txt) file2.txt >> file3.txt
```

In case both files have dos endings use

```
join -t';' <(dos2unix file1.txt) <(dos2unix file2.txt) >> file3.txt
```